# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) this error come while running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run this python code to create and update stack in AWS by deploying the cloudformation template I have placed the template in the s3 bucket

```py
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

from datetime import datetime
import logging
import json
import sys

import boto3
import botocore

cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')
log = logging.getLogger('deploy.cf.create_or_update') 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')  
    log = logging.getLogger('deploy.cf.create_or_update') 
    main(event['stack_name'], event['template_bucket'], event['template_key'])
def main(stack_name, template_bucket, template_key):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    cf = boto3.client('cloudformation') 

    template_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=template_bucket,Key=template_key)
    template_json_data = template_data['Body'].read(template_data['ContentLength'])
    template_d =json.loads(str(template_json_data))
    template_data_sudeep = str(_parse_template(template_data))
      params = {
        'StackName': stack_name,
        'TemplateBody':template_d
        }

    try:
        if _stack_exists(stack_name):
            print('Updating {}'.format(stack_name))
            stack_result = cf.update_stack(**params)
            waiter = cf.get_waiter('stack_update_complete')
        else:
            print('Creating {}'.format(stack_name))
            stack_result = cf.create_stack(**params)
            waiter = cf.get_waiter('stack_create_complete')
            print("...waiting for stack to be ready...")
            waiter.wait(StackName=stack_name)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as ex:
        error_message = ex.response['Error']['Message']
        if error_message == 'No updates are to be performed.':
            print("No changes")
        else:
            raise
    else:
        print(json.dumps(
            cf.describe_stacks(StackName=stack_result['StackId']),
            indent=2,
            default=json_serial
        ))


def _parse_template(template_data_sudeep):
    with open(template_data_sudeep) as template_fileobj:
     template_data_sudeep = template_fileobj.read()
    cf.validate_template(TemplateURL='https://bu123456.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cloudtemplate.json')
    return template_data_sudeep



def _stack_exists(stack_name):
    stacks = cf.list_stacks()['StackSummaries']
    for stack in stacks:
        if stack['StackStatus'] == 'DELETE_COMPLETE':
            continue
        if stack_name == stack['StackName']:
            return True
    return False


def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        serial = obj.isoformat()
        return serial
    raise TypeError("Type not serializable")


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main("sudeepstack", "bu123456", "cloudtemplate.json")
```

This is my cloudformation template which i have placed in the s3 bucket.

```py
{
    "Resources": {
        "Ec2Instance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"
                    }
                ],
                "ImageId": "ami-0d9462a653c34dab7",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a"
            }
        },
        "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access via port 22",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can not figure out the problem. It would be great if anyone help me about this issue. Thank you.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "d:/pythonwork/createstacks3.py", line 96, in <module>
    main("sudeepstack", "bu123456", "cloudtemplate.json")
  File "d:/pythonwork/createstacks3.py", line 25, in main
    template_d =json.loads(str(template_json_data))
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

initially i have write this code

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals

from datetime import datetime
import logging
import json
import sys

import boto3
import botocore

cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')  
log = logging.getLogger('deploy.cf.create_or_update')  

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cf = boto3.client('cloudformation')  
    log = logging.getLogger('deploy.cf.create_or_update')  
    main(event['stack_name'], event['template_bucket'], event['template_key'])
def main(stack_name, template_bucket, template_key):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    cf = boto3.client('cloudformation') 

    template_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=template_bucket,Key=template_key)
    template_json_data = template_data['Body'].read(template_data['ContentLength'])


    template_data = _parse_template(template_data)

    params = {
        'StackName': stack_name,
        'TemplateBody':template_json_data
        }

    try:

        if _stack_exists(stack_name):
            print('Updating {}'.format(stack_name))
            stack_result = cf.update_stack(**params)
            waiter = cf.get_waiter('stack_update_complete')
        else:
            print('Creating {}'.format(stack_name))
            stack_result = cf.create_stack(**params)
            waiter = cf.get_waiter('stack_create_complete')
            print("...waiting for stack to be ready...")
            waiter.wait(StackName=stack_name)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as ex:
        error_message = ex.response['Error']['Message']
        if error_message == 'No updates are to be performed.':
            print("No changes")
        else:
            raise
    else:
        print(json.dumps(
            cf.describe_stacks(StackName=stack_result['StackId']),
            indent=2,
            default=json_serial
        ))


def _parse_template(template_data):
    with open(template_data) as template_fileobj:
     template_data = template_fileobj.read()
    cf.validate_template(TemplateURL='https://bu123456.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cloudtemplate.json')
    return template_data





def _stack_exists(stack_name):
    stacks = cf.list_stacks()['StackSummaries']
    for stack in stacks:
        if stack['StackStatus'] == 'DELETE_COMPLETE':
            continue
        if stack_name == stack['StackName']:
            return True
    return False


def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        serial = obj.isoformat()
        return serial
    raise TypeError("Type not serializable")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main("sudeepstack", "bu123456", "cloudtemplate.json")
```

but i have got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/pythonwork/createstacks3.py", line 97, in <module>
    main("sudeepstack", "bu123456", "cloudtemplate.json")
  File "d:/pythonwork/createstacks3.py", line 31, in main
    template_data = _parse_template(template_data)
  File "d:/pythonwork/createstacks3.py", line 65, in _parse_template
    with open(template_data) as template_fileobj:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict
```

then i have added 
    template_d =json.loads(str(template_json_data))

Comment: Post the entire stacktrace. Also, what is the value of `str(template_json_data)` in this line: `template_d =json.loads(str(template_json_data))`?

Comment: i have done some editing in my question please see that .when i am printing template_json_data is the data which i have passed in the template. but in the positional argruments used in the code i have given the bucket name and template key as in name of the file which i have uploaded in s3 bucket.actually i am a begineer in this i got some references and by through i have wrote this code....my main motive is to deploy the 
AWS cloudformation template through python code

Comment: You pass `template_data` (a `dict`) into `_parse_template`. You probably want to pass in a `str` which is in that `dict`. What are its contents? Add `print(template_data)` on the line before `template_data = _parse_template(template_data)`. I assume there is a filename or filepath in there.

Comment: {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '0FEF68F7B6957505', 'HostId': 'dGb+Vs+VFm6bLPRU46x410+wUOR8kRzhGSRo/b4jm2z4iEclO9Aq1gQ7n6Q5d6kYwqNJXpvIK5U=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'dGb+Vs+VFm6bLPRU46x410+wUOR8kRzhGSRo/b4jm2z4iEclO9Aq1gQ7n6Q5d6kYwqNJXpvIK5U=', 'x-amz-request-id': '0FEF68F7B6957505', 'date': 'Fri, 13 Mar 2020 12:56:20 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Fri, 13 Mar 2020 12:51:25 GMT', 'etag': '"1f04a03b5f08aca59dc82df050c0f0ad"',

Comment: 'x-amz-version-id': 'hV4IXpDJhSOg3pMvbN0DFZLUVzh.lh9_', 'accept-ranges':
'bytes', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '958', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 13, 12, 51, 25, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ContentLength': 958, 'ETag': '"1f04a03b5f08aca59dc82df050c0f0ad"', 'VersionId': 'hV4IXpDJhSOg3pMvbN0DFZLUVzh.lh9_', 'ContentType': 'application/json', 'Metadata': {}, 'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x0000024498D76340>}

Comment: this is printing while i was printing print(template data) befor the line template_data = _parse_template(template_data).

Comment: Okay. In this line: `with open(template_data) as template_fileobj:` you are trying to open a file for reading, but instead of a valid filename, `template_data` is a `dict` with seemingly no relevant keys or values. I know nothing about AWS so I can't really help.